# Is there an open source vending-machine script for NFT minting?

Tags: nft, minting

Many projects either use a vending-machine service like [NFT-Maker PRO](https://www.nft-maker.io/pro) or [buffybot](https://buffybot.io/) or have built their own vending-machine scripts.

Is there any open-source vending machine script that can be connected to a cardano-node to mint NFTs when a UTxO arrives on a specific address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my version of a vending machine:

- Upgraded with metadata creation
- "Completed" counter backed up in a `*.txt` file so if the machine restarts the script does not start minting from the beginning
- You should create your own Blockfrost project
- Picture uploaded to Infura
- Sorry for the Hungarian comments

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/cardano/cnode/priv/wallet/cpostal
looping=1
log=log_file.txt
txs=txs.txt
numberCompleted=`cat numbercompleted.txt`

# ez lesz raymond címe, most a sajátom
donationAddr=`cat rajmond_yoroi_address`

# erre a címre várjuk a befizetéseket
paymentAddr=`cat payment.addr`

paymentSignKeyPath=./payment.skey
policySignKeyPath=./policy/policy.skey
scriptPath=./policy/policy.ada.2.120.script

POLICYID=$(cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file $scriptPath) > policy/policyID

# ez az én yoroi-s stake címem
profitAddr=`cat yoroi_address`

echo "" >> $txs
echo "" >> $log
echo "Log File" >> $log
echo "-------------------" >> $log
echo "Process started at: $(date +%T)" >> $log
echo "-------------------" >> $log
echo "" >> $log

arcedula=50000000 # ennyit kérünk ezért az NFT-ért

trap 'looping=0;wait' INT TERM

while (( looping )); do
    echo ================================================================================== 
    cardano-cli query utxo --address $paymentAddr --mainnet > fullUtxo.out
    tail -n +3 fullUtxo.out | sort -k3 -nr > balance.out
    cat balance.out
    while read -r utxo; do
        sleep 5s
    #echo "UTXO detected" >> $log
        tx_hash=$(awk '{ print $1 }' <<< "${utxo}")
    echo "TXHash: "$tx_hash
    idx=$(awk '{ print $2 }' <<< "${utxo}")
        utxo_balance=$(awk '{ print $3 }' <<< "${utxo}")
    tx_in="--tx-in ${tx_hash}#${idx}"
    if [ $( grep -q "${tx_hash}" "$txs" && echo $? ) ];
    then
       # echo "Previous tx" >> $log
        echo "nem trténr  utalás"
        break
    else
        echo ${tx_hash} >> $txs
        echo "utalás trtént"
        echo "A küldő cím: " >> $log
        echo $(curl -H 'project_id: *********' \
                https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/txs/${tx_hash}/utxos \
                | jq '.inputs' | jq '.[0]' | jq '.address') >> $log
            in_addr=$(curl -H 'project_id: *********' \
                https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/txs/${tx_hash}/utxos \
                | jq '.inputs' | jq '.[0]' | jq '.address' | sed 's/^.//;s/.$//')
            echo "Address: ${in_addr}"
        echo "utalás értéke: "$utxo_balance
            if [ ${utxo_balance} != $arcedula ] || [ $(ls "/opt/cardano/cnode/stamps/s1/" | wc -l) == 0 ];
            then
            echo ${utxo_balance} >> $log
            echo "Refund Initiated..." >> $log
        echo `date` >> $log
        echo "Pénzvisszafizetés"
            currentSlot=$(cardano-cli query tip --mainnet | jq -r '.slot')
                cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                    --fee 0 \
                    ${tx_in} \
                    --tx-out ${in_addr}+${utxo_balance} \
                    --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 1000)) \
                    --out-file tx.tmp >> $log
                fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
                    --tx-body-file tx.tmp \
                    --tx-in-count 1 \
                    --tx-out-count 1 \
                    --mainnet \
                    --witness-count 1 \
                    --byron-witness-count 0 \
                    --protocol-params-file protocol.json | awk '{ print $1 }') >> $log
                echo "Fee:"$fee >> $log
        fee=${fee%" Lovelace"}
                amountToSendUser=$(( ${utxo_balance}-${fee} ))
            echo ${amountToSendUser} >> $log
                cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                    --fee ${fee} \
                     ${tx_in} \
                    --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser} \
                    --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 1000)) \
                    --out-file tx.raw >> $log
echo "Pénz visszküldés submit" >> $log
         cardano-cli transaction sign \
                    --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath \
                    --tx-body-file tx.raw \
                    --out-file tx.signed \
                    --mainnet >> $log
echo "Pénz visszaküldés submit" >> $log
                cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx.signed --mainnet >> $log


# *******************************************NFT MINT *************************************
            else
            echo ========================================================= >> $log
        echo ======================== ÚJ NFT ========================= >> $log
        echo ========================================================= >> $log
        echo "Sending NFT..." >> $log
        echo `date` >> $log
            numberCompleted=$(( numberCompleted+1 ))
        echo "Token száma: $numberCompleted" >> $log
        echo $numberCompleted > numbercompleted.txt
#           POLICYID=$(cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file $scriptPath) ezt beépítetem az elejére, de ha minden nFT küln policit kapna akkor ide kell


#*********************** metadata gerebléyzés *****************

  tokenname=`cat /opt/cardano/cnode/stamps/s1/Stamp_Ada_$numberCompleted.png.ipfs.txt | awk -F'"' {'print $4 '} | awk -F'.' {'print $1'} | sed -e 's/_//g'`
tokennameID=`cat /opt/cardano/cnode/stamps/s1/Stamp_Ada_$numberCompleted.png.ipfs.txt | awk -F'"' {'print $4 '} | awk -F'_' {'print $3'} | awk -F'.' {'print $1'} | sed 's/^0*//'`
  ipfs_hash=`cat /opt/cardano/cnode/stamps/s1/Stamp_Ada_$numberCompleted.png.ipfs.txt | awk -F'"' {'print $8 '}`
echo "tokenname:" $tokenname >> $log
echo "tokennameID:" $tokennameID >> $log
echo "Poolpm név:"$POLICYID"."$tokenname >> $log


echo "{">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "      \"721\": { ">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "           \"$POLICYID\": { ">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "              \"$tokenname\": { ">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "                \"description\": \"CARDANO POSTAL SERVICE STAMP\"," >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "                \"name\": \"Ada Lovelace stamp $tokennameID\"," >> $tokenname"metadata.json" 
echo "                \"id\": $tokennameID, ">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "                \"creator\": \"Ildiko Kovacs\"," >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "                \"image\": \"ipfs://$ipfs_hash\"," >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "                \"url\": \"https://cardanopostalservice.io\"" >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "              }" >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "            }">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "        }" >> $tokenname"metadata.json"
echo "}">> $tokenname"metadata.json"
metadatajson="${tokenname}metadata.json"

echo ================
echo "mintelési adatok"
echo "tokenname:" $tokenname 
echo "tokennameID:" $tokennameID 
#cat $metadatajson

# **************** Bevétel szétdobása ********************

       amountToSendUser=1800000
((amountToDonate = arcedula * 5 / 100)) # ez magy rajmondnak
    
((amountToSendProfit = arcedula - amountToDonate - amountToSendUser))  # ez megy szabinak

echo 'vegleges szamok:'
echo 'arcedula:' $arcedula
echo 'amount to send profit:' $amountToSendProfit
echo 'amount to send user:' $amountToSendUser
echo 'amount to donate:' $amountToDonate

                currentSlot=$(cardano-cli query tip --mainnet | jq -r '.slot')
                cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                    --fee 0 \
                    ${tx_in} \
                    --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 $POLICYID.${tokenname}" \
                    --tx-out ${profitAddr}+${amountToSendProfit} \
            --tx-out ${donationAddr}+${amountToDonate} \
            --mint="1 $POLICYID.${tokenname}" \
            --minting-script-file $scriptPath \
            --metadata-json-file ${metadatajson} \
                    --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 10000)) \
                    --out-file tx.tmp >> $log
                fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
                    --tx-body-file tx.tmp \
                    --tx-in-count 1 \
                    --tx-out-count 3 \
                    --mainnet \
                    --witness-count 2 \
                    --byron-witness-count 0 \
                    --protocol-params-file protocol.json | awk '{ print $1 }') >> $log
            fee=${fee%" Lovelace"}
                amountToSendUser=$((${amountToSendUser}-${fee}))
                cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                    --fee ${fee} \
                    ${tx_in} \
                    --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 $POLICYID.${tokenname}" \
                    --tx-out ${profitAddr}+${amountToSendProfit} \
            --tx-out ${donationAddr}+${amountToDonate} \
            --mint="1 $POLICYID.${tokenname}" \
                    --minting-script-file $scriptPath \
            --metadata-json-file ${metadatajson} \
                    --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 10000)) \
                    --out-file tx.raw >> $log


echo 'amount to send user minusz fee:' $amountToSendUser
echo "Fee:"$fee

echo "NFT küldés aláírás" >> $log
                cardano-cli transaction sign \
                  --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath \
               --signing-key-file $policySignKeyPath \
                  --tx-body-file tx.raw \
                  --out-file tx.signed \
                  --mainnet >> $log
echo "NFT küldés submit" >> $log
              cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx.signed --mainnet >> $log
              
              
 
echo "============= mintelés vége =============" 
echo
            fi
            rm tx.*
        echo "====bejegyzés vége====" >> $log
        fi
     done < balance.out

  wait
done
```

I hope it help,
cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this MIT licensed Cardano NFT vending machine bash script available on GitHub. It hasn't been updated in 6 months, but you can fork it from the [ftpmorph repo](https://github.com/ftpmorph/Cardano-NFT-Auto-Mint/tree/main) and audit to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

We open-sourced one of these on GitHub here: https://github.com/thaddeusdiamond/cardano-nft-vending-machine

It's written in Python but requires no `cardano-node` (only `cardano-cli` and a [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) key).  There's also a sample script in `main.py` to show how to use it (or just invoke that script from CLI). Our PFP mint was done on my Macbook Pro.  Hopefully that helps!